# Determine creator of mail item in Exchange 2003 public folder

Tags: exchange-2003, public-folders, permissions

We have several users using a shared account and when messages in that account's in box have been processed they are drag and dropped into a public folder. Is there a way to determine who dropped a mail item in an Exchange 2003 public folder, so that we can have some accountability?

I suspect this can't be done natively in Exchange, so if there is a scripted solution to this I'd be very interested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *may* have luck examining the PR_CREATOR_NAME and PR_LAST_MODIFIER_NAME MAPI properties on the items. You can use the [MDBVU32](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=1784) utility to view these properties (background on doing that [is available in KB253291](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/253291)).

On my test machine (a Customer's E2K3 server I had close at-hand), though, I found that items I copied from my "Inbox" folder to a public folder did not bear a modified PR_CREATOR_NAME or PR_LAST_MODIFIER name different from the original sender. Your mileage may vary.

Comment: Bingo. For me it's showing exactly what I'm after. Now I just need to figure out how to do this programmatically. It's not like you need them but here's your 250 points.

Comment: @John: The Outlook object model doesn't expose PR_CREATOR_NAME. Do some searches on using CDO and you should find some code samples to do what you're looking for. I need the rep-- Chopper3 is getting too close for comfort... >smile<

Answer (score 1):

If it came be done, it would be located by going to **Exchange System Manager** > Expand **Servers** > Right click on your server and go to **Properties** > **Diagnostics Logging** tab > **MSExchangeIS** > **Public Folders**. I don't recall which one does it, either General or Access Control, maybe Views. Unfortunately it doesn't put it into a log file. It shows up in the application log.

Comment: I've had a really good play with those logging settings (as well as some others) but I can't find a setting which logs drag and drop. It was certainly worth a try though.